# Installing Nest Hello Doorbell

Tags: electrical, doorbell

[image: My wiring setup for the doorbell (no idea why it's sideways)]So my problem with this has nothing to do with the electronics - it's strictly a physical one.

The problem I'm having is that whoever wired my existing doorbell left about 1" of wire, with no give, and no ability to push anything back into the house, making the provided wire extenders useless.

Can I cut the wire connector from the wire extenders, strip the wire, solder it to the existing wire, and wrap heat shrink around the whole thing? Is there any danger to that?

I'd welcome any other suggestions that didn't involve soldering.

EDIT: I ended up going with clamp on forked terminators and an offset screwdriver to manage the angle. It works, but I wish nothing but pain on whoever set this up in the first place.

Comment: is there space inside the wall? ..... enlarge the opening horizontally if there is space

Comment: It doesn't appear there is. I ended up using clamp on forked terminators and an offset screw driver along with some swearing.